# What is the difference between "pupil" and "people"?

Tags: word-usage

Many times we heard that: Hall was packed with people. My question is can we say like this: 
Hall was packed with pupils or several pupil.

Comment: People are individuals, and pupils are students. You can say "the hall was packed with pupils" if a lot of students were in the hall. Note that _hall_ can mean a hallway (or corridor), or a large meeting room.

Answer (score 2):

***The** hall was packed with people.*

If the people in the hall are pupils from one or more schools, then you can say "The hall was packed with pupils". A hall cannot be 'packed' (full, crowded') with 'several' people.

If you want to know the difference between 'pupil' and 'people', look the words up in one of the dictionaries at  http://onelook.com/

Comment: _A hall cannot be 'packed' (full, crowded') with 'several people_. What do you mean by that? I disagree; halls **can** be packed with people.

Comment: @J.R. - I did not say that a hall cannot be packed with people. I said that it cannot be packed with *several* people.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. (I still think "cannot" might be an overly strong word, but you make an interesting point.)